# Phone conversations being recorded and played back

Tags: privacy, phone, gsm

Regarding [below post from 2014](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/can-you-listen-to-your-last-gsm-call-recorded-when-calling-back-a-user), I have the exact same problem with every call I make to Lebanon.
How do I stop this? Is it a bug?
I have factory reset my phone and it's still happening.

> My wife called a GSM/3G number abroad and the call was dropped. She called again and she could hear the whole conversation repeated with the other party but with blank period from her side of the conversation.
>
> How can this explained?
>
> The call originated from Saudi and terminated in Lebanon.

Comment: I asked my carrier and they said it's not them, they don't have permission. I also asked police , possibly immigration but they told me I still have to be notified and a court order has to be placed fir permission to record. So it's not a bug? Someone is definitely recording?

Comment: If it is a bug, how to remove?

Comment: Any news from this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a malfunction and to prevent it from happening (i.e. others listening to your conversations as well) it's best to **report it** to both carriers:

1. By email, and include:
2. Date and time of conversations with timezones
3. Source and destination number
4. Description of the problem

Comment: Thank you! I have actually called my carrier again, a year after first reporting it and them telling me they don't record calls, and they have advised me that this has been happening often in last six months with many customers! They have escalated the issue and I hope to have resolved in 24 hours. It should as you mentioned be only a technical malfunction from carrier. I will update with outcome of investigation